# Programmatically open a SSH tunnel in active session?

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I'm aware that *after* starting a new SSH session I can open the SSH shell to start a new tunnel (`Enter` then `~` and finally `C`):

```
>ssh -L 9000:localhost:9000
Forwarding port.
```

Is there a way to do it in a non-interactive way, while already SSHd in?

I'm ignoring security implications here, this is for local development situation where I might need to open a tunnel to a server which will be listening on a random port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it, with some preparation beforehand: setting the (first) ssh command as a master ssh, using [`-M`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh.1#M)/[`ControlMaster`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#ControlMaster) and [`-S`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh.1#S)/[`ControlPath`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#ControlPath). Normally the *ControlMaster* feature is intended to run multiple ssh shells to the same destination over a single ssh authentication using its single TCP connection. But you can also run an other ssh command with the [`-O` *ctl_cmd*](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh.1#O) to add the additional forwarding instead:

> `-O ctl_cmd`
>
> Control an active connection multiplexing master process. When the `-O`
> option is specified, **the *ctl_cmd* argument is interpreted and passed to
> the master process**. Valid commands are: “check” (check that the master
> process is running), **“forward” (request forwardings without command
> execution)**, “cancel” (cancel forwardings), “exit” (request the master
> to exit), and “stop” (request the master to stop accepting further
> multiplexing requests).

terminal1:

```
ssh -S /tmp/exampleinsecuresocket -M remoteuser@remotehost
```

terminal2:

```
ssh -S /tmp/exampleinsecuresocket -O forward -L 9000:localhost:9000 remoteuser@remotehost
```

Note that terminal2's ssh will immediately exit and not ask for authentication even if it should normally have been expected: it didn't do any connection to *remotehost* but just told the ssh already running in terminal1 to do the *LocalForward*. The ssh running in terminal1 now has an additional port forwarded. Of course this is non-interactive and can be done in a script.

With adequate use of parameters like `-o ControlMaster auto` and a correct scheme with adequate tokens for the *ControlPath* option as described in the manual, one can automate the initial settings in `~/.ssh/config` for any destination.

Comment: Perfect - that's exactly what I needed. You can see how these commands are used here: https://git.io/JkLVl  in this repo: https://github.com/lukaszkorecki/drifter